# Multioutput Classification in Spark

Tags: python, pyspark, classification, apache-spark-ml

Can we predict Multiple target variables in Pyspark, like we perform [MultiOutputClassifier()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier) in sklearn?

I have a datasetof multiple target variables

```
    Problem     Complexity  Skill1  Skill2  Skill3  Skill4  Skill5
0   Pbl1        Low            7      0       2       9      3
1   Pbl2        Medium         0      9       2       0      5
2   Pbl3        Medium         3      1       8       7      1
3   Pbl4        Medium         5      2       6       1      8
4   Pbl5        High           4      7       3       9      0
```

Here my independent variables are `Problem` and `Complexity` and I have to predict `Skills` for a particular problem and my target variables are `[Skill1, Skill2, Skill3, Skill4]`

In sklearn we can directly mention our 'X' variables and 'Y' variables and get the predictions for multiple columns with a single pass.
But in Pyspark we make all independent variables as `Features` and target variable as `Labels` column and apply machine learning on that data.

How can I make multiple target prediction for the above mentioned table structure in Pyspark?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our **[how to ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** guidelines and [edit] your question. Right now you can't read it at all...

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not provide a multiple target linear regression. It does provide a [Multinomial Logistic Regression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html#multinomial-logistic-regression) model; this is a classifier, so it's not appropiate for your problem.

What you *can* do is train one [Linear Regression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression) for each Skill target.

Answer (score 0):

If your data  is not big you can use `df.toPandas()` to convert your *spark dataframe* into *pandas dataframe* to implement [multioutput](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.multioutput) regression and classification tasks.