# What is the best practice to fit time-series based dataframe to predict multiple columns in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, time-series, regression

I'm experimenting with the [RandomForestRegressor](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-regression). The main dataframe created by [Aggregations on Windows over Event-Time](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/08/event-time-aggregation-watermarking-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html). Let's say below are train and test sets in the form of the dataframes including timestamp column (type `struct`):

```
#trainset dataframe
+------------------------------------------+----+.....+----+
|window_frame_24_Hours                     |A   | ... |Z   |
+------------------------------------------+---------------+
|{2021-11-28 00:00:00, 2021-11-29 00:00:00}|316 | ... |666 |
|{2021-11-27 00:00:00, 2021-11-28 00:00:00}|324 | ... |526 |
|{2021-11-26 00:00:00, 2021-11-27 00:00:00}|261 | ... |414 |
|{2021-11-25 00:00:00, 2021-11-26 00:00:00}|268 | ... |632 |
|{2021-11-24 00:00:00, 2021-11-25 00:00:00}|284 | ... |578 |
|{2021-11-23 00:00:00, 2021-11-24 00:00:00}|232 | ... |226 |
  ...                 ....                          ...
|{2021-11-02 00:00:00, 2021-11-03 00:00:00}|94  | ... |100 |
|{2021-11-01 00:00:00, 2021-11-02 00:00:00}|106 | ... |666 |
|{2021-10-31 00:00:00, 2021-11-01 00:00:00}|130 | ... |108 |
|{2021-10-30 00:00:00, 2021-10-31 00:00:00}|112 | ... |35  |
+------------------------------------------+----+.....+----+

#testset dataframe
+------------------------------------------+----+.....+----+
|window_frame_24_Hours                     |A   | ... |Z   |
+------------------------------------------+---------------+
|{2021-11-28 00:00:00, 2021-11-29 00:00:00}|??  | ... |??  | <-- predict
+------------------------------------------+----+.....+----+
```

following is my RF model implementation:

```py
#Dependencies
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.feature import MinMaxScaler
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressor, GBTRegressor
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder

value = X_train.columns[1:]

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=value,  outputCol='features')
scaler    = MinMaxScaler(inputCol='features', outputCol='scaled_features')

# Create a RandomForest model.
rf = RandomForestRegressor(featuresCol="scaled_features",  labelCol="label") #labelCol=value

# Chain model, assembler and scaler into a Pipeline.
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[assembler, scaler, rf])

# Train model on training data. 
rf_model = pipeline.fit(X_train)

# Make predictions.
predictions = rf_model.transform(X_test)

# Select example rows to display.
predictions = predictions.select("window_frame_24_Hours", "prediction", "features", "scaled_features").sort('window_frame_24_Hours.start')
##predictions.show(45, truncate = False)
```

I want to predict columns A - Z over certain time so I exclude timestamp column by `X_train.columns[1:]` and pass target columns via a `VectorAssembler` to `assembler`. Then:

when I use `labelCol=value` in `rf = RandomForestRegressor(featuresCol="scaled_features",  labelCol=value)` I face:

> TypeError: Invalid param value given for param "labelCol". Could not convert <class 'list'> to string type

when I use `labelCol="label"` in `rf = RandomForestRegressor(featuresCol="scaled_features",  labelCol=value)` I face:

> AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "A" among (window_frame_24_Hours, A, ..., Z,

the question:

- What is the best practice to fit time-series based dataframe to predict **multiple** columns. (multi-regression problem)
- Should I use for-loop and train for each column based on this disappointing [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708557/multioutput-classification-in-spark) for spark? if so, how?

I tried to check other time-series regression examples [1](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/time-series-forecasting-using-spark-ml-part-2-31506514c643), [2](https://www.twosigma.com/articles/introducing-flint-a-time-series-library-for-apache-spark/) & [3](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/01/apache-spark-and-facebook-prophet/) as well as this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k12pOgJp9_8) but their problem was not multi-regressions (predict lots of columns) nor it's not clear how they handle it. I know in in python there is solution for [Multioutput regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-regression).